# Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have these 2 classes

```
public class BrowserContext
{
    private readonly ChromeDriver _driver;

    public BrowserContext(ChromeDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }
    public void NavigateTo()
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bbc.com");
    }
}

public class Homepage 
{
    private readonly BrowserContext _browserContext;
    public Homepage(BrowserContext browserContext)
    {
        _browserContext = browserContext;
    }
    [Given(@"I navigate to url")]
    public void GivenINavigateToUrl()
    {
        _browserContext.NavigateTo();

    }
```

When I try to run the test I get below error

> Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not
>   supported! OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver (resolution path:
>   ClassLibrary3.Steps.Homepage->ClassLibrary3.Support.BrowserContext)

Please help!

Comment: I don´t see multiple constructors. Only one for every class.

Comment: code looks incomplete. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540905/multiple-constructors-with-one-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26402692/10148657 solution is to instantiate ChromeDriver in BrowserContext constructor rather than accept it in constructor:

```
public class BrowserContext
{
    private readonly ChromeDriver _driver;

    public BrowserContext()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public void NavigateTo()
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bbc.com");
    }
}
```